# Can't have internet on an Ubuntu 14.04.1 in Hyper-v

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, internet

I'm a developer so please perdon some naive terminology.
I have a virtual machine ( coming from VirtualBox ) that I moved to hyper V on my Windows 10 box. I cannot have the internet on that machine, I follow many discussion on the net, and what I did should follow what I read, but it does not work. So I share the step:
I created an internal switch on the Hyper-V management, because apparently Ubuntu/Hyper-V cant deal correctly with a DHCP. I added a legacy adapter, connected to that switch, like this:[image]
Advanced setting are like that:
[image]
Then I shared the internet, coming from my cable connection (ethernet ) as below:
[image]
So I supposed tyo have internet shared to my internal switch. The internal adaper IPv4 config is like below:

On the machine I tryed with bot ip configured as auto, or manual by setting an IP on the same subnet of the switch ( ie 192.168.137.2 ) nut, even if I can see the network apparently working, I have no internet access. What can I try?

[image]

Comment: **PLEASE** use the virtual switch manager **WITHIN** the Hyper-V Console.

Comment: @Daniel, what exactly you mean? I created it in the Hyper-V Console ( don't know how to do in other way ...)

Comment: 1st, undo every change in your network adapter. don't touch these! 2nd, check this out https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines

Comment: @Daniel Thank you, tried that as well ( actually before trying with the internal switch ), with no success.